# Como fazer círculos concêntricos no plot do r

Tags: r, plot

Preciso fazer círculos concêntricos, de preferencia deslocados da origem, na função `plot()` para servirem como referencia visual para uma função. Tentei o `abline()`, mas não obtive sucesso.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use o comando `draw.circle` do pacote `plotrix`:

```
x <- seq(-3, 3, by=0.01)
y <- x^2
plot(y ~ x, asp=1, type="l")

library(plotrix)
draw.circle(1, 1, 1, border="red")
draw.circle(1, 1, 2, border="green")
draw.circle(1, 1, 3, border="blue")
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A sintaxe do comando `draw.circle` é bem simples:

- o primeiro argumento é a coordenada do centro do círculo no eixo x
- o segundo argumento é a coordenada do centro do círculo no eixo y
- o terceiro argumento é o valor do raio do círculo

Alterei a borda deles com o argumento `border` só pra enfatizar a diferença entre os círculos desenhados. Por padrão, a borda deles é preta.

Answer (score 1):

Construindo sobre a excelente resposta do Marcus Nunes, você também poderia usar a função `symbols()` do pacote `graphics`.

Lembre-se apenas de usar `add=TRUE` (para ele acrescentar o círculo a um plot preexistente) e `inches = FALSE`, para que a escala natural do raio do círculo, informado em `circles`, seja a do eixo `x`.

```
x <- seq(-3, 3, by=0.01)
y <- x^2
plot(y ~ x, asp=1, type="l")

symbols(1, 1, circles=1, inches=FALSE, fg="red", add=TRUE)
symbols(1, 1, 2, inches=FALSE, fg="green", add=TRUE)  # circles é o 3º arg
symbols(1, 1, 3, inches=FALSE, fg="blue", add=TRUE)
```

Abs!